# pip installed module points to anaconda path rather than actual path

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, conda, setuptools

I have the following python module in my git repo that I checkout and I `pip install my_package` within an already existing conda environment with the same name `my_package`.

```
my_package
├── Makefile
├── data
├── my_package(renamed src so that I could import `my_package`)
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── data
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── script.py
│   ├── utils.py
├── setup.py
├── test_environment.py
└── tox.ini
```

I have a `data` directory outside the the code base where I keep my data and would like to access it in `script.py` using relative paths.

```
from pathlib import Path
my_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent 
do something with my_path
```

The problem is `my_path` returns my anaconda path and not the current path of the file.

I tried `pip install -e . my_package` and `pip install --install-options"--prefix=$(pwd)" my_package` and this doesn't seem to work the minute I try and execute a script in the sub `my_package` directory.

How do I get `my_path` to point to my current directory?

my `setup.py` looks like this. using python 3.7.3 and Mac OSX

```
from pathlib import Path

setup(
    name="my_package",
    packages=find_packages(),
    version="0.2.0",
    description="",
    author="",
    license="",
    install_requires=[
        "numpy", "pandas", "pytest"
    ],
)
```

Comment: Have you considered using `os.getcwd()`? Or is that not applicable in your case?

Comment: I don't want to do a getcwd() just because I might execute it from a different directory.

Comment: I did a `pip install -e ./` and that seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install -e ./`

solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access data, then it is best to make it part of your package, see [*setuptools* documentation on "Including Data Files"](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files).

The reason why is that when you install your Python project, you don't have much control over the exact location where your code ends up being written. And usually, files that are not part of a Python package are simply not installed alongside your Python code. So your code can't reach your data.

When you use the *editable* (`pip install -e .`) or the *develop* (`./setup.py develop`) modes, it works, yes, but it is more of a coincidence. Because the code is not actually installed (it is only pointed at), its location on the file system doesn't change and its relative location to the data doesn't change either.

On the other hand if you package the data correctly with the rest of the code, then it doesn't matter where it ends up being installed, the data is installed along with it. The code can then always find the data, see [*importlib.resources*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) to see how to write code that can read package data.